# Divisibility as an $R$-module vs as an abelian group

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a domain and $A$ an $R$-module. Exercise 2.38 (ii) in Rotman's An Introduction to
Homological Algebra says

> Prove that if the multiplication $\mu_r \colon A \to A$ is a surjection for all $r \neq 0$, then $A$ is divisible.

Am I right in thinking that the statement is false if one interprets the question as asking about the divisibility of $A$ as an abelian group? Any field of positive characteristic (as a module over itself) seems to be a counter-example.

My confusion arises from the fact that at this point in the book, divisibility has only been defined for abelian groups and not $R$-modules.

Comment: You are correct, divisibility as an $R$-module does not imply divisibility as a $\mathbb Z-$module.

Comment: It is better to not forget forgetful functors. When $A$ is an $R$-module, it is an $R$-module, not an abelian group. There is a functor $\mathbf{Mod}_R \to \mathbf{Ab}$, so $A$ has an *underlying abelian group* (which is *not* equal to $A$, since it does not know any scalar multiplication); saying "as a ..." is not a good idea. Unfortunately the underlying abelian group of $A$ is often written as $A$, even though this (also for other examples of forgetful functors) can be confusing ... The question here is about the statement that this forgetful functor does not preserve divisible objects.